# What is the best way to get started writing a hook for Mercurial?

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, hook

I'm new to Mercurial and want to write some hooks to prevent merging between certain branches and the like. I'm looking for some kind of tutorial that goes through the whole loop.

I've looked at the [API](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi) and these [examples](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HookExamples), but I still find it confusing. I've always been better at learning through a tutorial/workshop than by reading a man page or similar.

I can understand how the example code works, but how do I get Mercurial to recognize the functions?

e.g.)
I've written this, but I don't understand how to make Mercurial run the code before a commit.

```
def is_bad_branch_name(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    """
    Checks that a commit is always done on a named branch.
    This function enforces Projectplace's branching convention.
    @return: True if the branch name is invalid.
    @returntype: Boolean
    """
    branch = repo[None].branch()
    branch_names = r'(TT|AZ)(-#)(\d)+(:)[\s\w]*'
    acceptable_branch_names = re.compile(branch_names)
    if not acceptable_branch_names.match(branch):
        ui.warn('invalid branch name %r (use <TT|AZ>-#<number>: <description>)\n')
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Did you get to the point of trying, or are you still looking for the best way to dive in?

Comment: I've written some code, but failed to make Mercurial recognize it. I'll look at chapter 10 as soon as possible and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to write and make use of hooks now. I found the online documentation lacking, but that might just as well be a problem on my part. What I did was study example code and some trial and error coding as well as ask some questions here. :)

*edit*
For future reference this is the kind of line Mercurial needs in your hgrc to run the above code before a commit. That is a section for hooks and the paths to the code.

```
[hooks]
precommit.bad_branch_name = python:/path/to/hook/hook.py:is_bad_branch_name
```

You will need one line for each function you want to hook. "precommit" means that the hook will be run just before a commit is performed. This way the commit will be aborted if the hook returns True. "bad_branch_name" is just an identifier, you can type anything there.

Comment: Although it is nice to know that you have solved your problem, it would be nicer still if you would post a bit of what you did here. That way, when other people have the same problem and end up here they might be able to fix whatever does not work for them.

Answer (score 1):

Let me point out the obvious for the sole reason of me being a desperate rep wh***:

"[Chapter 10. Handling repository events with hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html)" in BoS's definite hg book.

If you can't figure out a particular hook you want, please ask a more specific question.

Happy hooking!

Comment: Um, it seems like a fairly valid question MdaG has asked.  Why so negative?

Comment: Sorry I meant my answer is for rw, not the question. Edited.